# Python find string enclosed in single quotes

Tags: python

In python how to find the string is enclosed within single quotes

```
  arr=["string","string'1" ,"'string2'"]

   for i in arr:
      if i //string enclosed in single quotes condition
            print "found"
            print i //which sould print only string2 in this case
```

Comment: What if the string is `"12'34'56"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way would be to check whether it both starts and ends with a quote:

```
if i.startswith("'") and i.endswith("'"):
    print "found"
```

That won't of course tell you anything else such as whether it contains matched quotes or indeed contains more than just a single quote character. If that matters then add in a check that the string is longer than one character (or greater than 2 if you want it to contain something between the quotes):

```
if i.startswith("'") and i.endswith("'") and len(i) > 1:
    print "found"
```

Comment: @perreal, so you are downvoting because of the comment "That won't of course tell you anything else such as whether it contains matched quotes or indeed contains more than just a single quote character."?

Comment: @perreal, fine so I put in the obvious additional check. Happy now?

Comment: @Duncan, it is not about the obvious check, I just wanted to emphasize that startswith/endswith are not miracles.

Comment: @warwaruk, are you aware that someone mass downvoted all the answers that does not use startswith/endswith? There is serious misguidance I think.

Comment: no, I wasn't aware. Anyway, I think you could comment on the answer in order to improve it instead of just downvoting it. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=["string","string'1" ,"'string2'"]
for item in arr:
    if len(item) > 1 and item[0] == item[-1] == "'":
        print "found", item
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
arr=["'","''","'''","'item","'item'","i'tem'"]
for i in arr:
    if(len(i) > 1):
        if i.startswith("'") and i.endswith("'"):
            print("found")
            print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
found
''
found
'''
found
'item'
```

if the first and last letters are equal and equal to `'`, then the string starts and ends with quotes. Ignoring strings of length 1 as they could be a single quote, assuming this could cause a problem for your system.

Comment: See PEP8: Use `''.startswith()` and `''.endswith()` instead of string slicing to check for prefixes or suffixes.

startswith() and endswith() are cleaner and less error prone. For example:

Yes: `if foo.startswith('bar'):`
No:  `if foo[:3] == 'bar':`

Comment: @perreal I modified my answer, it was

Answer (score -1):

```
arr=["string","string'1" ,"'string2'"]
for each in arr:
  if each[0] =="'" and each[-1] =="'":
     print 'found'
     print each
```

Comment: What if `arr=["string","string'1" ,"'string2'", "", "'string3"]` ?

Comment: See PEP8: Use `''.startswith()` and `''.endswith()` instead of string slicing to check for prefixes or suffixes.

startswith() and endswith() are cleaner and less error prone. For example:

Yes: `if foo.startswith('bar'):`
No:  `if foo[:3] == 'bar':`

Comment: and I repeat, what if `arr = [""]` ? That's why `startswith` and `endswith` exist, it is very easy to get this wrong if you subscript or slice.

Comment: @BasicWolf, this is not a slice though, is it?

Comment: @perreal, consider it as a particular case of a slice.

Comment: @BasicWolf, there is something called a slice notation, which includes double columns. I think startswith-endswith are meant for multi-character [sub]strings.